# Download multiple excel files linked through urls in R

Tags: r

I have a list containing hundreds of *URL*s directly linking to .xlsx files for a download:

```
list <- c("https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=main.weeklyReport.Excel&web_report_id=980", 
          "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=main.weeklyReport.Excel&web_report_id=981", 
          "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=main.weeklyReport.Excel&web_report_id=990")
```

To download everything in the list, I created a loop:

```
for (url in list) {
  download.file(url, destfile = "Rapex-Publication.xlsx", mode="wb")
}
```

However, it only downloads the first file and not the rest. My guess is that the program is overwriting the same *destfile*. What would I have to do to circumvent this issue?

Comment: it's b/c you're downloading them all to the same name (as Robert Tan illustrated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
for (i in 1:length(list)) {
  download.file(list[i], destfile = paste0("Rapex-Publication-", i, ".xlsx"),  mode="wb")
}
```

Comment: for (i in 1:length(list)) {
  download.file(list[i], destfile = paste0("Rapex-Publication-", i, ".xlsx"),  mode="wb")
}

Comment: Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: Added missing comma to my answer, thanks for the correction :)